# Convert frequency vector to logical matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I would like to convert a frequency vector (i.e. the `colSums()` of a matrix) to one of the possible versions of the original logical matrix in `R`.

Something like:

```
    s <- c(1,2,3)
    # Some function of s
    # Example output:
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    0    0    1
    [2,]    1    0    0 
    [3,]    0    1    0
    [4,]    0    0    1
    [5,]    0    0    1
    [6,]    0    1    0
```

The order of rows is not important. 
Could someone give me a hint on how to do this?

Edit: Rowsums are always 1. The output can be considered a multinomial dataset where each row reflects an observation.

Comment: rowSums always 1?

Comment: What determines the position of 1?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Yes, I added that to the original post.

Comment: @akrun Chance and the total colsums. The desired output can be considered a multinomial dataset, were each row should have exactly one value of one, and the rest zeros. The colsums should equal the values in s however.

Answer (score 2):

```
s <- c(1,2,3)
result = matrix(0, nrow = max(s), ncol = length(s))
for (i in seq_along(s)) result[1:s[i], i] = 1
result
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    0    1    1
# [3,]    0    0    1
```

Keeping rowsums as 1

```
s <- c(1,2,3)
result = matrix(0, nrow = sum(s), ncol = length(s))
result[cbind(1:sum(s), rep(seq_along(s), times = s))] = 1
result
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    0    1
# [5,]    0    0    1
# [6,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Rowsums are always 1. I edited the original post. Thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(523)

s <- c(1, 2, 3)
n <- 6

sapply(s, function(i) sample(c(rep(1, i), rep(0, n - i))))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    1    1
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    0    1
# [5,]    0    0    0
# [6,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: Perhaps pass `n` into the function so it's explicit where that comes from, and isn't dependent on the enclosing environment?  `sapply(s, FUN=function(s,n){...}, n=n)`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my initial question. Rowsums are always 1. I edited it. Thank you for your input anyway. I will think about it and see whether I could come up with something that fits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Input:
s <- c(1,2,3)
# ...
set.seed(1) # For reproducibility
nr <- sum(s)
nc <- length(s)
mat <- matrix(0L, nrow = nr, ncol = nc)
mat[cbind(seq_len(nr), sample(rep(seq_len(nc), s)))] <- 1L

# Output:
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1
[5,]    0    1    0
[6,]    0    0    1
```